# What is wrong in this attempt at a clojure map rewrite

Tags: clojure

I'm new to clojure and have been following the awesome tutorial at http://www.braveclojure.com.

I am trying to code a new map function that will return a set of the results.

I have the code below so far, but I keep getting an error that says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter declaration "mapset" should be a vector
```

Here's the code (I am using Leiningen):

```
(defn mapset
"Works like map but returns a set"
; First call to the function
([f items]
  (mapset f items []))
; Other calls to the function
([f items result]
  (if (empty? items)
    (set result)
    (recur f (rest items) (conj result (f (first items)))))))

(defn -main
"Call the mapset function"
(mapset inc [1 1 2 2]))
```

My first version actually used `let` like below, throws the same error though:

```
(defn mapset
"Works like map but returns a set"
; First call to the function
([f items]
  (mapset f items []))
; Second call to the function
([f items result]
  (if (empty? items)
  (set result)
  (let [[item & other-items] items]
    (recur f (into [] other-items) (conj result (f item)))))))
```

Any help (as well as critique of the code) is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigating I realized I forgot to add:

```
[& args]
```

to the end of the docstring in the `-main` function, as in:

```
(defn -main
"Call the mapset function"
[& args]
(mapset inc [1 1 2 2]))
```